# Passing parameters in URL ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am creating an `ASP.NET MVC` application which will be shown in clients like `WindowsPhone`, `iOS`, `Android` apps in a `WebView` control or `iFramed` in other websites. I want to control some behavior and styles differently for my `ASP.NET` application depending on the client requesting my site.

One way I can achieve this is passing this information through headers like `ClientType=WindowsPhone` etc. and reading the header value where ever I need. But I am thinking if there is a clean way I can pass this information in URL. Something like

https://www.example.com/windowsphone/Manage/Index
https://www.example.com/ios/Manage/Index

and read the client type from the URL where ever needed in my code.
I was confused if `RouteConfig` can help me here.

Comment: The short of it is, yes it can, what specific problems are you having?

Comment: that is NOT cleaner or preferred way IMO.  The preferred way is to change the view based on screen size.  If there are going to be changes as far as data goes and wanting less stuff happening on mobile devices then simply detecting if device is mobile or not will work fine

Comment: why would a windows phone get a completely different view than say an android phone or iPhone ?  if there is a good reason , that of course can be done , but IMO should not be done through url to different views.

Comment: My website is show as part of a windows phone app, iOS app, andoid app and want to use lets say different css to align with corresponding app style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it the following way,

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{clientType}/{controller}/{action}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
   constraints: new { clientType = new ClientTypeConstraint() });
```

and my ClientTypeConstraint looked like the following

```
public class ClientTypeConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
   public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
   {
       // Validate routeValueDictionary["clientType"] here
   }
}
```